# How can I manipulate char pointer contents?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am writing a C program that expects a filename as its argument. The program will read the contents of the file, and will output an other file (with a similar name, same extension but with an appended characters at the end of the name).

For example, if I run the binary like this:

```
./a.out some_file.txt
```

Then a new file will be created `some_file_out.txt`.

> ```
> New File Created: [some_file_out.txt]
> ```

My code below works, but it is too ugly. I am sure there is a better way of doing this. I considered working with `std::string` and that would simplify things, but I won't be able to use the string value with `fopen()` since it only accepts `char*` variables the filename.

What is a better way of manipulating a `char*` variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // validate argc count and that argv[1] file exists
    // assume all validation is done. For simplicity's sake.

    char* input_file = argv[1];
    /* do something with the file*/

    char output_file[strlen(argv[1]) + 4];  // reserve a new char[] with the same size
                                            //  as the input file, plus 4 characters for
                                            //  the output filename variation

    // assuming the extension is 3 characters long in all cases
    int dot_location = strlen(argv[1])-4;

    // copy characters from input filename to output filename
    for(int i=0; i<dot_location ; i++) {
        output_file[i] = input_file[i];
    }

    // add the name variation:
    output_file[dot_location  ] = '_';
    output_file[dot_location+1] = 'o';
    output_file[dot_location+2] = 'u';
    output_file[dot_location+3] = 't';

    // add the extension back
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {

        int new_index = dot_location + i + 4;
        int old_index = dot_location + i;

        output_file[new_index] = input_file[old_index];
    }

    // make sure the last character is a null value (not required)
    // output_file[dot_location+8] = '\0';

    // do something with the output file...
    printf("New File Created: [%s]\n", output_file);

}
```

Comment: `std::string` is part of the C++ standard library, not C. And you can get a `char*` from a `std::string` using the `data` function

Comment: I don't mind working with C++ if it will make my life easier. How can I open a file with the filename stored in a string? @UnholySheep

Comment: If `output_file` is an array of `strlen(argv{1]) + 4` characters, and `dot_location` is `strlen(argv[1]) - 4`. Then is `dot_location + 8` a valid index into `output_file`? I recommend you draw the array on paper (using some example value for `argv[1]`) and do the arithmetic using arrows on the paper.

Comment: @UnholySheep Shouldn't that be a `const char *`?  I don't know any way offhand where the C-style string pointer from any `std::string` method allows the returned C string to be modified.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes it is valid. But it is not required anyways. I commented that line

Comment: The code `dot_location = strlen(argv[1])-4;` makes the assumption that the dot will always be at a fixed position counted from the end of the file name. I suggest to search for the dot using `strrchr`.

Comment: @Bodo I know how to search for the last occuraence of a dot in the filename. I wrote (assuming) to make the question simpler

Comment: BTW: you ned to check if `argv[1]` exists by checking if `argc > 1`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I did not include anything in my question about validation, since it will make the question too long. I have edited my question and added a comment to assume that I have already validated user command line input

Comment: @Ahmad it was just an observation.

Comment: No it's not a valid index. Lets say that `argv[1]` is `"foo.bar"`. Then strlen(argv[1])` will be `7 and `output_file` will be an array of `11` (`7 + 4`) elements. And `dot_location` will be `3` (`7 - 4`).  That means `dot_location + 8` will be equal to `3 + 8` which will be equal to `11`. Which is ***out of bounds*** because the array indexes are zero-based. The array `output_file` will have indexes from `0` to `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use std::string for this usage, just use `str.c_str()`.

But to answer your question about C coding. I do something like this :

```
// find extension position
int ext_pos = strrchr(filename, '.') - filename;
// allocate new string
char newname[strlen(filename) + 4 + 1]; // +1 for null byte

strncpy(newname, filename, ext_pos); // copy first part
strncpy(&newname[ext_pos], "_out", 4); // write _out
strcpy(&newname[ext_pos + 4], &filename[ext_pos]); // copy extension and add null byte
```

Comment: `strrchr` will return `NULL` if the command line argument does not contain a dot. In this case subtracting `filename` is undefined behavior, so you should check the return value first.

Comment: @Bodo I can check for a valid name, and a valid argument. Thanks. I just needed this logic

Comment: @Ahmad You should **always** check the return value of a function that may indicate an error before using the return value, so the right thing to do would be e.g. `char * dot_ptr = strrchr(filename, '.'); if(dot_ptr == NULL) { /* handle error */ } int ext_pos = dot_ptr - filename;`

Comment: Beware of `strncpy`! It's not at all a safer alternative to `strcpy`. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It depends what you mean by safer. In this example, the `strncpy` does not provide any more safety than `strcpy`, as a string of a known length is copied. But in general it is safer to use `strncpy` when you don't know the length of the string you have to copy and you may exceed the buffer limits. I'd like to know other arguments of why it is not at all safer. I could be missing something.

Comment: @VladRusu yes, you're missing the fact that with `strncpy` the destination string may end up without the `NUL` terminator. So if the buffer is too small, the destination string won't have a NUL terminator and you'll get into trouble next time this string is used.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Of course. But every time one allocates or copies into a buffer they should be aware of this and count the null as part of the string. On the other hand, `strcpy` will try to write the `NULL` terminator outside the bounds if you try to copy a string with the length exactly as the buffer size and you can even mess up other allocations (may end up overwriting malloc headers from the next allocation). I see your point, but in these cases none of these functions provide any safety, and it's the programmers responsibility to manage the memory properly.

Comment: @VladRusu is right. The output of this code should be a null terminated string. Here the null byte is written by strcpy, but there is not enough bytes in the result string. I edited the answer